# Excel: when combining column chart and line chart, position of the line

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to obtain the following chart: for each month, a column chart representing the amount of money spent, and line chart representing the amount of money I had at the beginning of the month.

The problem that I have is that when the line chart is made, the values are set in the center of the column (see below).

[image: Excel screen shot]

What I would prefer is that the blue reference point is not center-aligned in the chart, but rather left-align.

Is is possible to configure this without having to manipulate the data and use a secondary axis or such trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that will work as long as you don't mind space between each column:

1. Introduce a third data series with values all being `0`
2. Generate your chart as before with the third series as the first column. Your chart should look like this:

[image]

(before you ask: you will need to keep the space between columns)